# console shows 6 when i multiply integer (3) into string ("2") in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arithmetic-expressions

Hey could you please tell me why this happens when I add

```
var a = 3
var b = "2"
console.log(a + b ) // 32
```

the above output is right
But when I do subtraction then it shows

```
console.log(a - b ) // 1
```

and it is the same for multiplication (o/p:- 6) and when I divide the output is (1.5) why this is happing
when I do other arithmetic operations except for addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '+' operator when operated on string does concatenation. The 'b' variable is a string literal and thats why you are getting output '32'.

Comment: I know about the this but why this happens when I do other arithmetic operations like multiplication, substraction, divide

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator is pecial in this sense. It will add numbers, but concatenate if it encounters a string.

However, a behavior like this **makes no sense** for other operators.

For example, what do you expect `"foo" - 2` to do? And `"foo" / 3`? Divide `"foo"` into  3 parts? Then what about `3 / "foo"`?

So, the general rule is rather that **arithmetic operators always coerce their arguments to numbers**, and the **addition / concatenation  operator(`+`)** is the only **exception**.

---

Actually, the comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) can also work on strings, but those aren't arithmetic operators.